# substring respecting whole words. Vue.js

Tags: vue.js

Is there a way to use something like substring for showing only a certain number of words, so that it doesn't cut the words, but cuts on the spaces only? I want to do this for shortening a description when showing the item.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can search for the first space after the remaining string.

```js
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    message: "Let's all unite to fight the novel coronavirus"
  },
  methods: {
    shorten: function(string, len) {
      return string.substring(0, len + string.substring(len - 1).indexOf(' '));
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <span>{{ shorten(message, 11) }}</span>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: If I'm using something like a vue html editor, it saves the string a little different, with things like `<span></span>`, `<ul></ul>` and other html stuff, could I still use this method?

Comment: I have updated to how you can use it that way

Answer (score 0):

You can `split` the sentence by space, then get the first x words from the array (`slice`) and `join` them with space again.

An example to get only the first 3 words.

```js
let sentence = 'Is there a way to use something like substring'
let newSentence = sentence.split(' ').slice(0, 3).join(' ')
```

Comment: If I'm using something like a vue html editor, it saves the string a little different, with things like `<span></span>`, `<ul></ul>` and other html stuff, could I still use this method?